# Check if an object has a type from a given namespace in python3

Tags: python-3.x, types, namespaces

I have a namespace say Hello (say a class named Hello with some classes like World and other classes inside it)

there are several objects of type 'Hello.World.A', 'Hello.Everyone','Hello.People' etc...

I want to check if a variable x has a type that belongs to namespace/class `Hello`
a check that holds true for all types in namespace/class `Hello`

```
a = Hello.World()  # creating an object of Hello.World
b = Hello.World.A()
c = Hello()
d = Hello.People()
```

i want a condition that holds true for all these objects.

for example

```
def belongs_hello(obj)
   if type(obj) belongs to Hello:
        return True
   else:
        return False

belongs_hello(a) # True
belongs_hello(b) # True
belongs_hello(1) # False
```

The real thing that I am trying to do is something like :

```
def __init__(self,inp):
    if type(inp) is str:
        self.soup = self.get_soup(inp) # extract soup if url is given
    elif type(inp) is_some_decendant_of BeautifulSoup:
        self.soup = inp
    else:
        raise Exception('requires string(url) or element of beautifulsoup as argument')
```

I need something for `is_some_decendent`

Comment: Depending on what is `type(hello)` this may not be possible. `a` may not know it "belongs" to anything called `hello`, especially considering that Python supports dynamic attributes creation

Comment: say hello is a class

Comment: if we print type(a) it gives `<class 'hello.world'>`

Comment: `a` and `b` are the returned value of methods, not the methods themselves. This question is not really answerable unless we know the types of everything

Comment: sorry my bad. those are not methods. hello, hello.world are classes. say hello is a class and world is an inner class and I am constructing their objects by calling hello.world()

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is `print('Hello' in str(Hello.world))`. However, this feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186270/discussion-between-srbcheema1-and-deepspace).